# 1 of 2 cronjobs not running in Ubuntu 16.04 for windows - due to `date` expansion in cron

Tags: bash, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two cronjobs in my crontab.  The first works; the second doesn't.  Specifically,

```
40 18 * * * cp /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/daily_winner /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/`date +'%b-%d-winner'`
```

doesn't work.

I have tried:

```
- commenting out the first one
- removing the full path for the destination file and checking the default DIR for my user
- using a relative path for the dest file
- looking through 5 other cronjob questions on this site
- looking for the cron log file but it doesn't exist.  Before someone tells me to check syslog, please note it doesn't exist on my installation.
- **I removed the ">>/var/log/cron_output.log 2>&1" and just left the command**
```

`Aviator@AW:/var/log$ ls
alternatives.log  btmp          dpkg.log        fsck     lxd                  upstart
apt               dist-upgrade  fontconfig.log  lastlog  unattended-upgrades  wtmp
Aviator@AW:/var/log$`

```
35 18,21 * * * /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/winner
40 18 * * * cp /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/daily_winner 
/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/`date +'%b-%d-winner'` >>/var/log/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Have you try to create shell script instead of adding all commands in cron?

Comment: That's actually a great idea.  The first job that works is, in fact, a script.  I can just add the cp line to the bottom.  I am still curious why a simple cp is failing to execute in crontab though.

Comment: maybe the execution of `date +'%b-%d-winner'` do not go well. Do you want to add it as answer (if this resolve your problem)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you for the suggestion (to add it to my script) and it does work as expected - I just tested.  I don't want to add it as an answer as the original question is still unsolved.

Comment: instead of date execution add static string and try to run it again (in cron w/o script)

Comment: A static filename at the end worked so it is related to date expansion.  I tried `cp /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/daily_winner /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/$(date +'%b%mwin')` instead of backticked date expansion but that didn't work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187791/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-adrian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% characters in cron need to be escaped whereas they don't if in a script or directly on the cmd line.

After escaping them the cronjob ran as expected.

```
cp /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/daily_winner /mnt/c/Users/Adrian/pick_of_the_day/$(date +'\%b\%mwinner')
```

Relevant answers I just located:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252615/why-doesnt-date-f-t-work-in-crontab